how to auto sum the calculated field
I have below pivot table and calculated field column in excel. Not able to get the grand total for calculated column.It is simply subtracting the value 1 from 'num' column as per calculated field formula.How to simply get the sum of Caculated field column.
I have below:



user id
num
calculated field




a
23
22


b
45
44


Grand Total
68
67



What I want is below:



user id
num
calculated field




a
23
22


b
45
44


Grand Total
68
66



